# python redis init data type on windows

Tags: python

I setup redis on my windows system ,and setup python envirment,now I try set data to redis like this

import redis

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

r.set('b', 'ccc')
r.set('a', '钱猛')    


print(r.get('a'))
print(r.get('b'))
```

and I get the results is this

```
b'\xe9\x92\xb1\xe7\x8c\x9b'
b'ccc'
```

why get data is binary data ， I do nothing with the redis config,  binary is the init config ? and How can I save data is simple data, and get data like this

```
ccc
钱猛
```

Comment: Try: `b'\xe9\x92\xb1\xe7\x8c\x9b'.decode('ISO-8859-1')`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an encoding issue, Not the data type casting issue. Please refer [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) for resolving your issue. Thanks